# Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined in javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Console I got following error using e.preventDefault() method
I used e as a function parameter

```
  function function1(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
```

1533 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined.

Called function1 like

```
    <a href="#none" onclick="function1()">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: syntax error - function(e)

Comment: if you are calling that function without parameter then it will throw that syntax error

Comment: How are you using the function `function1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remove event from function and invoke function in this way:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="btnSave" type="submit"                                           
          onserverclick="btnSave_OnServerClick"  onclick="return 
          jsFunction();">Save</button>
```

In JavaScript:

```js
function jsFunction() {
        alert('call');
        if ($('#form1').bootstrapValidator('validate').has('.has-error').length) {
            alert('SOMETHING WRONG');             
        } else {
            alert('EVERYTHING IS GOOD');
            __doPostBack('<%=btnSave.UniqueID%>', '');
          }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 33):

You have to pass `event` in the used function:

```
function1(event); // where you called it
```

For example:

```
    <a href="#none" onclick="function1(event)">Click Me</a>
```

Make sure you call this function within an event handler. Such as :

```
 $(document).click(function(event){
      function1(event);
 });
```

Comment: on button click event i called this function1

Comment: on submit button click i called this function1

Comment: Can you add your click event in your question?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="btnSave" type="submit" onserverclick="btnSave_OnServerClick"  onclick="jsFunction();">Save</button>

Comment: function jsFunction(event) {
            alert('call');
            if ($('#form1').bootstrapValidator('validate').has('.has-error').length) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                alert('EVERYTHING IS GOOD');
                __doPostBack('<%=btnSave.UniqueID%>', '');
            }
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 2):

You are writing the function wrong. Suppose you are using function on a particular button click having id as 'clickBtn' then you need to write function like this.

```
$("#clickBtn").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<a href="#none" onclick="function1()">Click Me</a>
```

Instead of that:

```
<a href="#none" onclick={function1}>Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

You failed to pass the event as a parameter in your in luck event in the html. 
So it should be written as the sample below:

```
<a href="#none" onclick="function1(event)">Click Me</a>

function function1(event){
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Note that you use `event` as a parameter, but inside the function `e` is still being used.